# Jenkins - Is it possible to store old builds in another directory?

Tags: jenkins

Say you have 2 artifacts.

- example.msi
- example2.msi

When example2 is built, I want the first build/artifact (example.msi) to be stored in another directory on disk so that I can only see example2.msi in our last successful artifacts.

Is this possible to do in Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a post-build action to archive your old artifact. [Here](http://codurance.com/2014/10/03/guide-to-deploying-artifacts-with-jenkins/) is a way to do it.

Comment: But what about deleting artifacts from the "Last Successful Build" section?

Comment: With post-build action you could also chose to run a script where you do the cleaning stuff.